# How fix _JAVA_OPTIONS on Debian

Tags: java, linux

I installed Java stuff (Java 8 , 9) on Debian and I cannot run programs in Intellij, when i do `-javac -version` int Terminal i get this message:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=gasp
javac 9.0.1
```

Do you have idea how to fix it, I cant find solution in the Internet. I tried to add `_JAVA_OPTIONS='-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=gasp` to bashrc but it didnt help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to pass arguments to the Java virtual machine. To do so, from your IDE, you should look for a `Run configuration` option, once you select your project, there is an input box labeled `VM arguments` or something similar. You have to put there whatever you want to pass to the `JVM` as argument.

Comment: Ok, it helped. I made new Run configuration. The program works but still after all outputs there is `Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=gasp` Have you idea how to delete it?

Comment: If it helped you can accept and vote the answer. Maybe you have enabled some log to show the java options?

Comment: Copy and paste the text from the console on a pastebin.

Comment: Try to check if you have `_JAVA_OPTIONS` as environment variable, and remove it if it is.

Comment: In ~/.pam_enviornment?

Comment: Use `printenv` to list all variables.

Comment: I did and on this list there is JAVA_OPTIONS

Comment: use `unset variable_name` to remove a variable.

Comment: Works only in Terminal but not in Intellij,  I think it doesnt matter. Thanks a lot